# My old laptop doesn't want to start. Is it possible to pick some important files

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop

Well, it was a really big accident.

Some days ago, I bought a new laptop and today evening, I was transfering some files from my old laptop to my new laptop. Unfortunately, I dropped my old laptop, and after that the laptop doesn't want to start. It shows startup repair. and of course, it doesn't solve any problem.

Be cuz I bought a new, broken or not broken it is not matter. However, I havent't finished yet moving my files from old to new laptop. Some my pictures and codes(programming) are left there and I don't want to lose them.

So the question is, when laptop doesn't want to start normally(I haven't tested safe mode yet.), is it possible to get datas or files and send that to another laptop??

Comment: If the hard drive was damaged in the drop, you don't want to be trying to boot from that drive or attempt "repairs" to it - until you've copied your data off. And if the data was important, you really should have had backups already

Answer (score -1):

You can always take apart the old computer to find the hard drive, and buy a cheap USB hard drive adapter to connect it.

Comment: Plugging the drive directly into a desktop's SATA might be even better, sometimes those adapters don't work well. Or remove the *new* laptop's hard drive and plug in this old hard drive, but boot from a USB (linux, or apparently windows runs from a USB sometimes if microsoft lets it) then upload data from the old drive to somewhere secure online

Comment: Assuming the disk is not totally broken you can start from USB with tools like RIP `https://sourceforge.net/projects/riplinuxmeta4s/files/release/` and try to read the folders.